# How can I make JDK 7 the default JDK in NetBeans?

Tags: java, path, netbeans, jdk

I uninstalled JDK 1.6.26, then installed JDK 7 and changed my PATH to point to the new version.

However when I now open NetBeans it shows me this error:

[image]

> Cannot locate java installation in specified jdkhome:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
>   Do you want to try to use default version?

How can I make JDK 7 the default JDK that NetBeans uses?

Comment: The error message complains about 1.6.25 but you uninstalled 1.6.26 I am going to guess you forgot to do something.  Uninstall ALL versions of java and reinstall 1.7

Comment: i did this exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Locate `netbeans.conf` and change the following according to your JDK location:

```
"netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01""
```

It will solve your problem.

The file may not have writing permission for a regular user so make sure to give yourself permission to write the file if you are unable to save the changes.

Comment: thanks, i found it, and after editing it my problem has been resolved!

Answer (score 1):

First, try checking your other environment variables for references to the old path.  Specifically, check JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME.

I don't know about NetBeans, but Eclipse tends to remember the JDK location in an internal setting.  You may need to reset the path in the NetBeans preferences.

Finally, try searching your registry for references to the old JDK path.

Comment: i check Path and edit it for new version

Comment: but where is JAVA_HOME   and JRE_HOME

Comment: That depends on the OS you are using.  Google "setting JAVA_HOME windows XP" for example.